# How to use ServiceStack.OrmLite with a Xamarin Android project

Tags: servicestack, xamarin, ormlite-servicestack

Is it possible to use ServiceStack OrmLite on a Xamarin android project?  I'm having a hard time finding the right combination of dlls.  I've tried building from ServiceStack.OrmLite.Android.sln and using the resulting dlls, but when I add ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Android.dll to the solution I get the following error when I build:

```
Error   2   Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'System.Data.Linq.dll'
   at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(List`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(List`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   853 2   AndroidApplication1
```

I have seen some post around indicating they were able to use Ormlite with a Xamarin android project, but they don't have any details on the implementation and they are old enough that they probably used v3 of ServiceStack.

I'm using the starter edition of ServiceStack, although i don't think that would have any impact.

Thanks,
Estyn

Comment: Are you sure OrmLite was being used successfully within a Xamarin project? I'm not finding any evidence that there is support for this.

Comment: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/tree/master/src  There is a branch here and I've seen some forum posts about it, I will try Skall's recomendation and report back

Comment: I added Android and iOS support back in v3 which I am still using. There seems to be new updates recently though so someone must be using it in v4 as well (I don't know if starter edition will support everything though): https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/e96d8ca4f666ee3d5d6716465d6e66678ba4ecc4

Answer (score 1):

Either build the V3 branch source code or get the DLL's from here:

https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile/tree/master/libs/ServiceStack

You can also fork this branch of ServiceStack.OrmLite if nothing else works, it's where I first published OrmLite Android & iOS support: https://github.com/sami1971/ServiceStack.OrmLite-1